# "Declare default JavaScript includes" - load only for some nodes

Tags: javascript, drupal, themes, lazy-loading, drupal-7

I am using Omega theme in Drupal 7. And I know that you can declare default JavaScript files inside `mytheme.info`. But this is globally declared and is loaded each time on every node, even on the node where I don't need the `js` file. And this is resource consuming and more over is making site slower.

Is there a possibility from the theme configuration, to specify that `js` file is only for a certain node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would suggest adding the js from init hook in your custom modules.

```
mymodule_init(){
  if(arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(0)) && node_load(arg(1))->type == 'my_content_type'){
    drupal_add_js(path_to_my_js);     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use **drupal_add_js()**, maybe in phptemplate_preprocess_html and wrap your condition around it .. dunno if you have the nid in the variables argument .., else use **current_path()**

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on JavaScript optimisation though I'm pretty sure it'll merge all your JavaScript files specified in `mytheme.info` into a single file, which will be good for your site's performance.

It'd probably be best doing this when you're putting the site live, otherwise debugging could be a bit tricky :)

Failing that the [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) function should help you add page-specific JavaScript.